# Is there a way to tell make to apply a rule to every file that matches a pattern?

Tags: make

I am working on a project that has a directory structure that looks a bit like this:

```
inputs/
   a.txt
   b.txt
   c.txt

outputs/
   a.out
   b.out
   c.out

makefile
```

The files in the `outputs` folder are generated from the files in the `inputs` folder and I want to automatically update them whenever one of the input files changes.

I tried to do this by creating a makefile with a pattern rule. (To keep this question simple, I'm just copying the input file instead of transforming it)

```
outputs/%.txt: inputs/%.out
    cp $< $@
```

However, this makefile didn't quite do what I want. If I run `make outputs/a.txt` it will apply the rule that I wrote and regenerate the output file if it is outdated but if I just run `make` then nothing happens:

```
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

Is there a way to tell make that by default I want to generate an output file for every file in the inputs folder?

**edit**: made the output files have a different file suffix than the input files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would typically do this with a makefile something like this:

```
IN = $(wildcard inputs/*.txt)
OUT = $(subst inputs/,outputs/,$(IN))

outputs/%.txt: inputs/%.txt
        cp $< $@

default:  $(OUT)
```

This makes the default target (the first one in the file), depend on `OUT` which is the glob expansion of the existing files in `IN` with the directory string changed from inputs to outputs.

---

If you want to change the suffix there are lots of other builtin functions to manipulate the targets. For example you can add an intervening operation:

```
IN2 = $(addsuffix .out,$(basename $(IN)))
```

The `basename` function will remove the trailing `.txt`, and the `addsuffix` will add a trailing `.out`.

Comment: What if I want to change the file suffix for the files in the `outputs` folder to something other than `txt`? I can't think of a clean way to do that with subst...

Comment: There are many functions in [gnu make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Functions.html). I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: For anyone who is wondering about "cp $< $@": https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html